# Mix and match table elements and table-styled elements

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this code:

```
<style>
tr, .bar{
    display: table-row;
}
th, td, .pcell{
    display:table-cell;
    border: black solid 1px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <table>
        <div class="bar">
            <label class="pcell">Stuff</label>
            <label class="pcell">moose</label>
        </div>
        <tr>
            <td>Other Stuff</td>
            <td>cow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div class="pcell">More Stuff</div>
            <td>chicken</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

I want to be able to replace table cells with labels without replacing a whole table.  Is there a way to achieve this? I would be alright with replacing only a row, just not an entire table.

I am trying to create a header row with selectable labels adapted from [this](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) tutorial.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a solution, but it does not fit into a comment.

this is not valid html. the browser will first parse you html code.
because a `div` is not a valid child of `table` or `tr` the browser tries to correct this, and does some *magic*. e.g. in chrome this html code would be transformed into this:

```
<div class="bar">
     <label class="pcell">Stuff</label>
     <label class="pcell">moose</label>
</div>
<div class="pcell">More Stuff</div>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Other Stuff</td>
        <td>cow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>chicken</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

because of that your css code does not have the expected result.

Why do you want to use labels, wouldn't a `th` and `thead` work ?

Comment: I have seen the result. The result is the thing that I am trying to not achieve. The reason is complicated. See the link I provided. I have a table with hidden radio buttons in the header, for switching how the data is sorted. Please don't answer unless you have an answer rather then a vague ("magic") description of whats happening.

Comment: @AaronSchif As said, it's to long for a comment, but it explains, that you shouldn't create invalid html, because of the different error handling. (http://www.w3.org/wiki/Validating_your_HTML#Different_browsers_interpret_invalid_HTML_differently). And even if it is defined (html5) then you could have created this corrected result right from the beginning. therefore you only need to know that the browser does some _magic_ (browser specific rules for handling invalid html) with the code, but not how. and it's still not clear why you don't do some think like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/MdamF/1/